# How to Aggregate list of tuples in python?

Tags: python

Input- 
`[(0, 48), (0, 1474), (1, 2709), (1, 27), (1, 2)]`

Output- `[(0, 2), (1, 3)]`

Output is computed by counting how many times did the first number in the tuple repeated in the list. My constraint is that I don't want to use Pandas. I have tried `collections.Counter(x[0] for x in tuples)` but it only gives me a list of [2, 3]. This is insufficient because there is no way to tell what element occurred 2 times or 3 times. How should I do that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is Pandas "not pythonic" ?

Comment: Also, this is not what `groupby` is for. You should probably use `collections.Counter`

Comment: @DeepSpace maybe you're correct but I can't use Pandas here. Business constraint.

Comment: Please provide input and expected output

Comment: @DeepSpace input is in the image. Its the object value seen in Pycharm debug mode. The output is `[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 13)]`

Comment: The thing is, some copy-pasteable input in text format would be much handier than a screenshot of input.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm sorry. I understand what you mean. I'm updating the question.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829422/counting-element-occurences-in-nested-lists). There's nothing wrong with using `Counter(x[0] for x in tuples)`, the problem comes afterwards - you're extracting only the values from it, instead of `(key, value)` tuples. I'm tempted to find a *"how to get `(key, value)` pairs from a dict"* duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Counter(x[0] for x in tuples)` but it only gives me a list of `[2, 3]`

This observation is wrong.

```
from collections import Counter

li = [(0, 48), (0, 1474), (1, 2709), (1, 27), (1, 2)]
print(Counter(x[0] for x in li))
# Counter({1: 3, 0: 2})
```

`Counter` always returns a dictionary. To get the output you want you simply need to sort by the keys and create the tuples you want (assuming that this is indeed the order you want your output to be in):

```
from collections import Counter

li = [(0, 48), (0, 1474), (1, 2709), (1, 27), (1, 2)]
counter = Counter(x[0] for x in li)
output = [(k, v) for k, v in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[0])]
print(output)
# [(0, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: The key function looks redundant. You'll get the same result with a simple `sorted(counter.items())`.