# Count number of occurrences of each unique item in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
listoflist = [["A", "B", "A", "C", "D"], ["Z", "A", "B", "C"], ["D", "D", "X", "Y", "Z"]]
```

I want to find the number of sublists that each unique value in `listoflist` occurs in. For example, "A" shows up in two sublists, while "D" shows up in two sublists also, even though it occurs twice in `listoflist[3]`.

How can I get a dataframe which has each unique element in one column and the frequency (number of sublists each unique element shows up in)?

Comment: would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829457/2572645

Comment: You said: "How can I get a dataframe...". Are you working with Pandas, and searching for a Pandas specific solution? If so, please mention it in the question and add a pandas tag to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use: `itertools.chain` together with `collections.Counter`:

```
In [94]: import itertools as it

In [95]: from collections import Counter

In [96]: Counter(it.chain(*map(set, listoflist)))
Out[96]: Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'X': 1, 'Y': 1, 'Z': 2})
```

As mentioned in the comment by @Jean-François Fabre, you can also use:

```
In [97]: Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(map(set, listoflist)))
Out[97]: Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'X': 1, 'Y': 1, 'Z': 2})
```

Comment: `it.chain(*map(set, listoflist))` => `it.chain.from_iterable(map(set, listoflist))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, it seems that you want something like

```
Counter(x for xs in listoflist for x in set(xs))
```

Each list is converted into a set first, to exclude duplicates. Then the sequence of sets is flatmapped and fed into the `Counter`.

Full code:

```
from collections import Counter

listoflist = [["A", "B", "A", "C", "D"], ["Z", "A", "B", "C"], ["D", "D", "X", "Y", "Z"]]

c = Counter(x for xs in listoflist for x in set(xs))

print(c)
```

Results in:

```
# output:
# Counter({'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'Z': 2, 'D': 2, 'A': 2, 'Y': 1, 'X': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(listoflist)
df.stack().reset_index().groupby(0)['level_0'].nunique().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'X': 1, 'Y': 1, 'Z': 2}
```