# Python count occurrence returns 0

Tags: python

I have a list that contains the name, age, and id of a person respectively. 
I want to count the number of occurrences of a given id within the list.

When I try:

```
alist=[(('john', 37), 8),(('john', 37), 8)]

count_ID=alist.count(8)
print count_ID
```

I receive:

```
count_ID returns 0
```

I expect it to return 2 in this example, as the list has 2 items that have id=8. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
alist = [ (('john', 37), 8), (('john', 37), 8) ]
sum(1 for x in alist if x[1] == 8)
```

You have to specify somehow that the `id` field is present as the second element in the tuple, then filter out only those tuples with `id == 8` and finally sum 1 for each one that was found - alternatively we could find out the length of the resulting list, but why creating a temporary list when a generator suffices?

As pointed out in the comments, this also works:

```
sum(x[1] == 8 for x in alist)
```

The above snippet works because in the comparison `x[1] == 8` a `True` value evaluates to `1` and a `False` evaluates to `0`.

Comment: Or just `sum(x[1] == 0 for x in alist)`.

Answer (score 2):

`alist.count(8)` would only work if `8` was an element of `alist`:

```
>>> alist = [(('john', 37), 8),(('john', 37), 8)]
>>> 8 in alist
False
```

`8`, however, is an element of the first element of your list:

```
>>> 8 in alist[0]
True
```

So to count the number of occurrences, you have to check to see if `8` is in each of the elements of `alist`:

```
>>> sum(i[1] == 8 for i in alist)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

The list has to be flattern.
Python does not count nested list. So it'd be:

```
alist=[(('john', 37), 8),(('john', 37), 8),8,8]
```

for python to return 2

and here is the [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828123/nested-list-and-count) to flattern the list