# Counting the list inside the list

Tags: python-3.x

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.']]
```

I would like to ask if how can I count the values inside the list. In this case, the value would be 6 not 2. Sorry I am not that familiar with the terms. Thanks!

Comment: Clear your question. What value you want to count ?

Comment: Sorry my english is bad. What I wanted to count is this ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'] that would return to 6 in this scenario.

Comment: Is there a method to use how to count inside the items inside the square brackets?

Comment: Yes.You can use `len()`. If I understand correctly, `length = len(grid[0])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a list of lists. It would actually look like this, just adding a bracket to the end:

```
grid = [
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.']
]
```

[This other question has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828123/nested-list-and-count).

Comment: Yes. It is list of list. I wasn't able to add 1 bracket at the last. My bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the length of each nested list you can use a list comprehension

```
[len(sub_list) for sub_list in grid]
```

> [6, 6]

If you want the unique values of the lengths, you can use a set-comprehension

```
{len(sub_list) for sub_list in grid}
```

> {6}