# How to count how many times a word appears in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list in python

```
texts = [
    ["great", "even", "for", "the", "non", "runner", "this", "sound",
     "track", "was", "brilliant"],
    ["cannot", "recommend", "as", "a", "former", "comrade", "i", "did",
     "not", "want", "to", "have", "to", "do", "this"]
]
```

and I want to go through the list and count how often each word appears in it.

I have tried counting the individual words using `length()` and I get a `2` as a result which means it does not work.

Is there any way I can count how often a word appears in a list as I intend storing the counted word in a new list and it's frequency in another list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We won't know how to make the problem go away in your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post your [mcve](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. Explain the problem, and what output should be produced for this input.

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828150/3620003) is in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is probably that `texts` is a nested list, which is also why you get `2` for `len(texts)` since `texts` contains 2 sublists.

If you want to iterate over the individual words, you need to iterate over the sublists and then over the words inside the sublists. Luckily, Python's list comprehensions can be nested:

```
[word for words in texts for word in words]
```

As for the counting: The standard library has a dictionary class for exactly such purpose: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
word_counts = collections.Counter(word for words in texts for word in words)
```

This will give you a dictionary mapping individual words to their occurrence count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) for this.

```
texts = [
    ["great", "even", "for", "the", "non", "runner", "this", "sound",
      "track", "was", "brilliant"],
    ["cannot", "recommend", "as", "a", "former", "comrade", "i", "did",
      "not", "want", "to", "have", "to", "do", "this"]
]

for text in texts:
    cnt = Counter()
    for word in text:
        cnt[word] += 1
    print(cnt)
```

Comment: Note that `texts` is a nested list.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

texts = [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"]]

words_count = Counter(chain(*texts))
print(words_count)

>> Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can count the words with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

texts = [["great", "even", "for", "the", "non", "runner", "this", "sound","track", "was", "brilliant"],
         ["cannot", "recommend", "as", "a", "former", "comrade", "i", "did", "not", "want", "to", "have", "to", "do", "this"]]

for text in texts:
    print(Counter(text))

# Counter({'great': 1, 'even': 1, 'for': 1, 'the': 1, 'non': 1, 'runner': 1, 'this': 1, 'sound': 1, 'track': 1, 'was': 1, 'brilliant': 1})
# Counter({'to': 2, 'cannot': 1, 'recommend': 1, 'as': 1, 'a': 1, 'former': 1, 'comrade': 1, 'i': 1, 'did': 1, 'not': 1, 'want': 1, 'have': 1, 'do': 1, 'this': 1})
```

Source: [How do I count unique values inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282232/how-do-i-count-unique-values-inside-a-list)